# Splitting a string up via markers?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have a txt file that is an excerpt from a book. I have converted the file to a string via the following method

```
    File book = new File("WarAndPeace.txt");
    chapters = new ArrayList<String>();


    FileReader fileReader;
    fileReader = new FileReader(book);


    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(nextLine);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }
    fileReader.close();

    myBook = stringBuffer.toString();
```

In the text file, each chapter is contained withing a volume. It is denoted by "CHAPTER" and then a roman numeral. For example, the fifth chapter begins with "CHAPTER V"

I need to break the string up into multiple strings and add them all to an ArrayList so I can write functions such as "nextChapter()" "previousChapter" "getChapter(int volumeNumber, int chapterNumber" which will return applicable strings. For example I was thinking this; where chapters is an ArrayList

```
public String nextChapter(){
currentChapter++;
return chapters(currentChapter);
}
```

How do I split the book into chapters and volumes (a volume contains a number of chapters)

Do I need to use a different data structure than ArrayList, and if so what and how? I've heard a HashMap can use keys (maybe a type String holds two keys, chapter and volume?) and if so, how do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to change also the algorithm that reads the book from a file?

Comment: And how is denoted a volume?

Comment: `myBook.split("Chapter [IVX]+\\s+")`, perhaps?

Comment: To expand on @Teepeemm maybe `ArrayList<String> chapters = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myBook.split("Chapter [IVX]+\\s+")));`

Answer (score 1):

**In regards to file parsing:** [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) is a very useful tool. It supports [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), meaning you can provide it with something like `"CHAPTER [IVXLCDM]+"` and it will match any occurrence of "CHAPTER" followed by roman numerals. However, keep in mind that regex is *case sensitive*. Also, using this method will not respect the actual numbers of the chapters; whichever chapter comes first is what will be put first in the resulting array. This will likely not be a problem, as most books contain their chapters in order.

If you use the example match from above, you may have to strip newlines from the beginning and/or end of the chapter text. [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) will do this for you.

**In regards to data structures:** In this sort of case, object-oriented programming can benefit you a lot. Instead of using an `ArrayList<String>` to hold the chapters of your book, you should create classes for the different parts of a book. For example, an instance of class `Book` could have an array of `Volume` instances, each of which would have an array of `Chapter` instances. `Chapter` might contain a single `String` with the chapter's content, and possibly another `String` for the title.

It may seem like more work now, but it pays off in the long run. Classes provide the user with a consistent interface and also allow you as the programmer to protect your data. By defining methods like `Volume getVolume(int)` or `Chapter getChapter(int)`, you provide the user with a cleaner and more meaningful way to interact with your data. In contrast, calling a method of `List` can be more ambiguous in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is not difficult, but not so simple as a simple splitting by keywords. In a real book text, you could easily find the word "chapter" within the text. So, if you split by ocurrences of "chapter" you would end up with spurious divisions and a wrongly built data structure.

Thus, you have to be careful about the criteria to consideer that the text "chapter" (or "volume") is actually a chapter heading. You have stated one:

- A chapter is headed by the word "CHAPTER" plus sume spacing plus a roman number.

I would add the next:

- This heading occupies a full line of text.

And a similar rule for volumes, with the word "VOLUME" (if no other criteria is specified).

So, if you are already reading the file by lines, you'd better do the text analisys *while reading the file*, getting thus a better opportunity to distinguish where a line starts and ends, and also to avoid storing big amount of data within a string (which usually turns on a poor performance). So, the data structure should be built in the process of analyzing text.

The data structure should be something like this:

```
class Book
{
    private List<Volume> volumes=...
    public void addVolume(Volume volume) {...}
    public Volume getVolume(int volume) {...}
    public Chapter getChapter(int volume, int chapter) {...}
}

class Volume
{
    private List<Chapter> chapters=...
    public void addChapter(Chapter chapter) {...}
    public Chapter getChapter(int chapter) {...}
}

class Chapter
{
    private StringBuilder text=...
    public void addText(String text) {...}
    public String getText() {...}
}
```

And the parsing algorithm goes like this:

```
Pattern chapterPattern=Pattern.compile("CHAPTER\s+[IVXLDC]+");
Pattern volumePattern=Pattern.compile("VOLUME\s+[IVXLDC]+");
Book book=new Book(...);
Volume currentVolume=null;
Chapter currentChapter=null;
while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (volumePattern.matcher(nextLine)).matches())
    {
        // It is a volume heading:
        currentVolume=new Volume(...);
        currentChapter=null;
        book.addVolume(currentVolume);
    }
    else if (chapterPattern.matcher(nextLine)).matches())
    {
        // It is a chapter heading:
        currentChapter=new Chapter(...);
        currentVolume.addChapter(currentChapter);
    }
    else
    {
        currentChapter.addText((nextLine).append("\n"));
    }
}
```

This parsing algorithm always expect that the book is well formed: It must always begin with a volume heading. After a volume heading, there must be a chapter heading. And all volumes and chapters must appear sequentially (so the roman numeration can be ignored). If not, an ugly exception will arise. So, if you want to get under control possible wrong formattings, you'll have to take in account a `null` value in currentVolume or currentChapter.

Also, there is nothing specified about empty lines. Is it legal to have an empty line between volume heading and chapter heading? If so, you'll have to take it in account.